# NSDateFormatter with RSS pubDate

Tags: objective-c, feedparser

I have some problems with converting a rss pubdate string into a NSDate object.

```
<pubDate>Fri, 09 Sep 2011 15:26:08 +0200</pubDate>

NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"EEE, d MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss Z"];
NSDate *date = [dateFormatter dateFromString:currentDate];
NSLog(@"DateObject : '%@'", date);
[dateFormatter release];
```

I always get

```
 [44157:10d03] DateObject : '(null)'
```

Answer (score 7):

You'll need:

- `dd` instead of `d`, since the day is zero-padded
- `ZZ` instead of `Z`, since it doesn't include the timezone abbreviated name

More info: http://unicode.org/reports/tr35/tr35-4.html#Date_Format_Patterns

---

When I run this:

```
int main (int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    NSAutoreleasePool *pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];

    NSString *str = @"Fri, 09 Sep 2011 15:26:08 +0200";

    NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"EEE, dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss ZZ"];
    NSDate *date = [dateFormatter dateFromString:str];
    NSLog(@"DateObject : %@", date);
    [dateFormatter release];

    [pool drain];
    return 0;
}
```

I get this:

> EmptyFoundation[19926:407] DateObject : 2011-09-09 13:26:08 +0000

Comment: I never worked with this before, but maybe there is another problem since this doesn't appear to work if used with the OP code. A [quick test](http://imageshack.us/f/577/screenshot20110910at135.png/).

Comment: With [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"EEE, dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss ZZ"]; it won't work :-(

Comment: I trim my pubDate by whitespaces and newline and now it works almost perfectly but the time is -2h because the timezone isn't set right.        pubDate: Mon, 05 Sep 2011 12:33:29 +0200
DateObject : 2011-09-05 10:33:29 +0000

Comment: @Philippxp: `NSDates` *always* log in the GMT timezone, because dates **do not have a timezone**.  They are an absolute point in time, and exist independently of timezones and calendars.  So `10:33:20 +0000` *is* `12:33:20 +0200`.  The date is correct.

Answer (score 1):

First you could try the following code:

```
NSString *str = @"Mon, 19 Oct 2015 14:27:28 +0800";
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"EEE, dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss ZZ"];
NSDate *date = [dateFormatter dateFromString:str];
NSLog(@"DateObject : %@", date);
```

However, If your `DateObject` is still `null` , your locale is not correctly located `"en_US_POSIX"` format. You need change your locale.

```
NSString *str = @"Mon, 19 Oct 2015 14:27:28 +0800";
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"EEE, dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss ZZ"];
NSLocale *enUSPOSIXLocale = [[NSLocale alloc] initWithLocaleIdentifier:@"en_US_POSIX"];
[dateFormatter setLocale:enUSPOSIXLocale];
NSDate *date = [dateFormatter dateFromString:str];
NSLog(@"DateObject : %@", date);
```

The result is:

> DateObject : 2015-10-19 06:27:28 +0000

Answer (score 0):

Use :

```
  NSArray *array=[string componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceCharacterSet]];
```

to split the pubDate by whitespaces and newline and then get every element you want to show by using the indexes of the array.

Answer (score 0):

I use this code to format Wordpress RSS feed dates:

```
 + (NSDate *)parseWordpressDate:(NSString *)dataWp {

    NSArray *array=[dataWp componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceCharacterSet]];

    //Tue, 04 Mar 2014 11:00:36 +0000

    //day = index 1, month = 2, year = 3
    NSString *yyear = [array objectAtIndex:3];
    NSString *mmonth = [array objectAtIndex:2];
    NSString *dday = [array objectAtIndex:1];

    NSDateFormatter *dateFormatterGMTAware = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [dateFormatterGMTAware setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MMM-dd"];
        NSString *dateString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@-%@-%@",yyear,mmonth,dday];
        NSDate *data = [dateFormatterGMTAware dateFromString:dateString];
        return data;

  }
```